# Reading binary data from database and use as attachement in mail with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I read the content of a file on my client, base64 encode it, send it via JSON to my Rails backend, base64 decode it and store the data in the database. I then try to send a email from Rails with the data as a attachement.

Here is my column definition of the binary data:

```
t.column :binarydata, :binary, :limit => 10.megabytes, :null => false
```

Here is my mail template:

```
class MYMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def mail(from, to, cc, bcc, subject, message, files=[], sent_at = Time.now)
    @subject = subject
    @recipients = to
    @from = from
    @cc = cc
    @bcc = bcc
    @sent_on = sent_at
    @body["message"] = message
    @headers = {}

    # attache files
    files.each do |file|
      attachment file.mimetype do |a|
        a.body = file.binarydata
        a.filename = file.filename
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Here is where I read from the database and send the email:

```
attachements = AttachementItem.find(:all)
MYMailer.deliver_mail("foo@home.com", "bar@home.com", nil, nil, "Attachement test", "This is just a test", attachements)
```

Here is the code that parses the incomming JSON and stores the data in the database:

```
attachement_json = params[:attachement]
attachement_json = attachement_json.gsub(/\n/, "\\n")
attachement = AttachementItem.new.from_json(attachement_json)
b64data = Base64.decode64(attachement.binarydata)
attachement.binarydata = b64data
attachement.save
```

However the attachements that I receive in my email is garbage. I do not know if the error is on my client side and I am investigation this also, but can you see if I have a error in my Rails code?

Thank you

Comment: What does `file.mimetype` do when attaching files? Does it properly set the mimetype for your uploaded file? Does the file look alright in the database? How are you determining that the file is garbage in the email client?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well my Rails code works! I found my errors (there where more than one), and they where all in my client code. Sorry for asking :)

Comment: OK, so how *did* you do it? What was the correct code?